# Unable to query with startAt and equalTo in Firebase JS

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my DB:

[image]

Here is my problem:
1) when i use below code it will return the object to me

```
firebase.database().ref(`/restaurants`).orderByChild('name').equalTo('Good Restaurant').on('value', snap=>{
      console.log(snap.val())
    })
```

but when i change the param of `equalTo` to  `${myInput}` with , then it will return `null`.

```
firebase.database().ref(`/restaurants`).orderByChild('name').equalTo(`${this.myInput}`).on('value', snap=>{
      console.log(snap.val())
    })
```

2) When i change `equalTo` to `startAt`, it will return `null` to me as well.

```
firebase.database().ref(`/restaurants`).orderByChild('name').startAt(`${this.myInput}`).on('value', snap=>{
              console.log(snap.val())
            })
```

---

Below is my IONIC html code for the input in case you suspect the input parsing got problem:

```
 <ion-searchbar
    placeholder="Please enter your restaurant Name"
    [(ngModel)]="myInput"
    [showCancelButton]="shouldShowCancel" (input)="onKeyUp()">
  </ion-searchbar>
```

**Edit**

Below is how the `onKeyUp()` function work:

```
myInput
inputTime
deplayTime = 1000

// as this is typescript, i don have to do "var" or "let"

onKeyUp(){
      console.log(this.myInput)
      clearTimeout(this.inputTime)
      this.inputTime = setTimeout(this.restaurantListing, this.deplayTime);
  }

  restaurantListing(){
    firebase.database().ref(`/restaurants`).orderByChild('name').equalTo(`${this.myInput}`).on('value', snap=>{
        console.log(snap.val())
      })

  }
```

So, when i type "Good", the `console.log(this.myInpit)` execute 4 times and display: "G", "Go", "Goo", "Good". After 1 second then it will only start executing `restaurantListing()`.

Please help and thank you in advance!

Comment: Make sure `this.myInput` has some value.

Comment: i did console.log it, it has the exact value that i type in the search bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to interpolate variables in Javascript class, unless you want to do something like `startAt('string ${this.myInput} string')`. So simply pass the variable:

```
firebase.database().ref(`/restaurants`).orderByChild('name').startAt(this.myInput)
```

**EDIT**

My guess was that `NgModel` updates its input after `onchange` event fires, so tried to `console.log()` that, but it appeared as not the case. However, looks like IONIC works like this - first calls `onKeyUp()` and then update ngModel's value. You can also console.log ngModel event and keyUp to see if you get `undefined`. To fix your bug try this:

```
<ion-searchbar
    placeholder="Please enter your restaurant Name"
    [value]="myInput"
    [showCancelButton]="shouldShowCancel" (change)="onKeyUp($event.target.value)">
  </ion-searchbar>
```

and `onKeyUp(change) { this.myInput = change }`

Comment: i tried, but it doesn't work, it will have the error : `ERROR Error: Query.equalTo failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'restaurants'`

Comment: updated - that can be more in Angular style - with ngModelChange, but that should work

Comment: updated my quetion as well, sorry that i didn't clarify how the onKeyUp work in my initial post. I applied a function to wait user finish typing then only execute the query code.

Comment: New find out, if i do `console.log(this.myInput)` in the  `restaurantListing()`, it will show `undefined`, although it did show "good" in the `onKeyUp()` function. Isn't it suppose will be "good" all the time?

Comment: Meanwhile, i tried your new suggestion, but i encounter error : `Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-searchbar'.`

Comment: Hm, now I am confused, as wrapping `this.restaurantListing()` with `setTimout` should have solved the `undefined` issue. You could also just set initial value to `myInput = ''`. Also you can find in docs, IOnic searchBar has its own event - `(ionInput)="onInput($event)"`, though I am not sure if that differs much from `input` event. Also to delay, you dont need setTimeout as it has a `debounce` event.

Comment: Oh, and what should work with your initial implementation is - `(input)="onKeyUp($event.target.value)"` and also use that passed in argument in `onKeyUp()` instead of `myInput`

Comment: Yea, it work with `(input)="onKeyUp($event.target.value)"`, but i have change the `(input)` to `(ionInput)`, so it will have slightly delay in order to wait user type, else DB will be busy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, maybe your this reference isnt right in that context

```
var input = this.myInput;

firebase.database().ref('/restaurants').orderByChild('name').equalTo(input).on('value', snap=>{
  console.log(snap.val())
})
```